# Tableau server or Desktop bug fixes demo

Tags: tableau-api

I have upgraded my `tableau desktop` and `server to 8.3 version,` and [here are the bug fixes](http://www.tableau.com/support/releases/8.2.6)

What I want to know is how do I create a situation in lower version and show that it has been resolved in newer version.

could somebody link me where these type of demos are given.?

I tried creating this bug in V 8.2.6 but it doesn't appear

`Example:`

`"Check clearing all selections on a quick filter in a map view, selecting another filter caused the view to display the previous filter selection before the new selection loaded"`

this is bug in `8.2.6` and resolved in `8.3`

Answer (score 1):

1. Demos of a bug occurring in one version and then not occurring in a later version may exist, but such demos are not provided by Tableau. If a bug is stated as resolved in a particular version of Tableau and yet continues to occur in that version or a later one, then please contact Tableau Technical Support with details of the issue, reproduction steps, screenshots and log files
2. Tableau's release notes describe the version in which the issue was resolved. If the [release notes for version 8.2.6](http://www.tableau.com/support/releases/8.2.6#Tableau-Server) include details of the aforementioned map view quick filter bug, then the bug was fixed in version 8.2.6 and thus will only occur in previous versions such as 8.2.5 or below